# How to calculate the ScreenPoint and Rect of a gameObject in unity with canvas render mode is "World Space"？

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I create a button in unity, and set the Canvas render mode to "World Space". Under this mode, How to calculate the ScreenPoint and Rect  of the button？

[image]

[image]

I have tried the below code, but it's not correct:

```
var position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position)

Vector2 size = Vector2.Scale (rectTransform.rect.size, rectTransform.lossyScale);
Rect rect = new Rect (rectTransform.position.x, Screen.height - rectTransform.position.y, size.x, size.y);
```

**please give some ideas?**

Comment: Can you describe a bit more? Like, what end result are you wanting or visual example?

Comment: @ZayedUpal I want to get the screen point and real size of the button displayed on the phone.  when I set canvas render mode to “Screen Space”, the up code is correct. but wrong for World space

Comment: Does all the values show wrong or only the rect height?

Comment: @ZayedUpal  yes,all the values are wrong. Could you please give some ideas？